# Using Django ORM to serialize data and related members

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-orm, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a REST api, using django. I started using the nice djangorestframework, which I loved to use the "View" class.
But, I'm facing with the serialization problem.
I do not like the Serialization using the Serializer classes.
The main goal is to prepare a sort of giant dict, with all the infos, and give it to a renderer class which translate it into an xml, json, yaml, depending on the "Accept:" HTTP header. The goal is classy, but 60% of the CPU time is spend on creating the "GIANT DICT".

This dict can be created using django Models, but I think using on the fly instanciated classes and object is VERY un-efficient ? I'm trying to use some QuerySet methods to filter which models member I want to have, and getting a simple dict : the ::values() method, but unfornately, I can't access the m2m and foreignkey from my models.

Did you already tried this ? Any though ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the QuerySet's [`iterator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator) method:

> ... For a QuerySet which returns a large number of objects that you only
>   need to access once, this can results in better performance and a
>   significant reduction in memory.

Your code should looks like:

```
for obj in SomeModel.objects.values_list('id', 'name').iterator():
    # do something
```

Comment: sounds interesting. I'll try it tomorow morning !

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the orm instanciate an object on the fly for each result. It's something that I don't want. using SomeModel.objects.values().iterator() could be very interesting BTW. But I do not want object generation, and I do need the relation (ForeignKey, M2M) in SomeMOdel :)

Comment: Yes, `iterator()` can be used with `values_list()`, sorry for not useful example. I've updated the answer

Comment: I'll try and see how it deals with M2M relations

Comment: But I think it doesn't meter what to use model instance or tuple, because if you don't pass it by reference garbage collector will delete in on the next iteration. Any way this is just guess, just profiling can find out what to use

Comment: In my case, using models waste CPU times :)

Comment: It very depends on model's desing. Some of them just like an DataObject but the other used OOP power and has some business logic. So you could chose what is more important architecture desingn or performance :)